# Raspberry: debug c++ application with NetBeans and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans-8, raspberry-pi3

I have done the setup of NetBeans with Qt (C++ language) with enough efforts.. I'm able to build, deploy in my Raspberry Pi3 and if I launch manually the application it works.
I would like to configure properly also the debug but it seems a problem defining paths and so on.
The error is:
[image]
The application is deployed in the folder: "/home/pi/NetBeansProjects/" and the application is HelloQtWorld_1.
This is the setup od debug in the project:
[image]
Is absolutely not clear how to setup paths and so on.. I tried a lot of different combinations.
One detail: the file ".gdbinit" doesn't exist in my pc.. should I have it?
It's as default.
And this is the setup of builder that is working properly:
[image]

Any idea? What else I have to check?

The Run configuration is this:
[image]
Even I guess the IDE will use Run or Debug depends on which button you press..

Comment: I use Netbeans to develop my C++ projects on a Linux VM from Windows via SSH and Samba, however never experienced it with QT. One quick thing is as I quickly checked my working configuration and it also has my Windows location gdb init "C:\Users\akhin/.gdbinit" as yours so I guess that is not it. Also there is "Debug" and "QT" sections in your screenshots ( and I think QT section only affects the compilation but not how you run as it is under "Build")  but what about "Run" section as I believe that is where it should be defined ?

Comment: I added the Run configuration above. One question: if you don't use Qt, how you can create GUI for your application? HMTL? I need a user interface and I'm searching a smart way. With Qt in combination with NetBeans it's a fake.. at the end you can draw forms, with controls but the code is not automatically updated..

Comment: After seeing run configuration, actually not sure. As mentioned did not use Qt with Netbeans , but one thing I would do to diagnose would be using https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx , I would apply a filter like "process name = netbeans/java executable AND path contains NetbeansProjects" , then I would spot the entry in which it fails to load the file in your first screenshot/error dialog. Then I`d go back in entries, to see the config files that your Netbeans accesses and try to figure out how it is concatenating.

Comment: As for UI part , I don`t have enough knowledge as I used MFC in C++ and did some .Net Windows forms. But, I hear a lot about HTML/Javascript and C++ combination either via QT Webkit ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336018/Building-C-Applications-with-HTML ) or by embedding WebKit directly into your application ( https://code.google.com/archive/p/chromiumembedded/ or others )

If applicable , I would look at separating UI layer and the actual logic part and perhaps use Kivy or QT with Python